# Jquery colone child count issue (nth-child)

Tags: jquery

I have a div called 'div.cloneFrame', and i am cloning that using jquery.clone. it works fine and i clone all i need, using this function :

```
var needToClone = 4;
    var totalImgs = 0;
    for(i=0;i<needToClone;i++){
        $('div.cloneFrame').clone()
        .removeClass('cloneFrame')
        .appendTo('.frame-group').each(function(){
            var imgSrcLength = $(this).find('img');
            for(j=0;j<imgSrcLength.length;j++){
                totalImgs++;
                $(imgSrcLength[j]).attr('src','imgs/outfits/'+totalImgs+'.jpg');
            }
        })
    }
    $('div.cloneFrame').remove();
```

later i need to select the cloned div, for that i am using the nth child function

```
$('div.myframe:nth-child('+1+')').addClass('incoming').next().addClass('outgoing');
```

But not work. in case if i use this :

```
$('div.myframe:nth-child('+3+')').addClass('incoming').next().addClass('outgoing');
```

it's working well. why it need skiping 2 numbers on nth-child? anything wrong from my side?

my HTML :

```
<div class="frame-group">

            <div class="cloneFrame myframe">
                <div id="orange-frame" class="product-frame">
                    <a class="purchase-btn" href="#">Purchase this item</a>
                    <img alt="women coat" src="imgs/yellow-coat.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="yellow-frame" class="product-frame">
                    <a class="purchase-btn" href="#">Purchase this item</a>
                    <img alt="blue coat" src="imgs/coat-blue.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="brown-frame" class="product-frame">
                    <a class="purchase-btn" href="#">Purchase this item</a>
                    <img alt="women shoe" src="imgs/women-shoe.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="green-frame" class="product-frame">
                    <a class="purchase-btn" href="#">Purchase this item</a>
                    <img alt="women jean" src="imgs/jean.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>


            <span class="outfit-no">outfit no.<span>01</span></span>
            <a class="buy-outfit" href="#">Buy outfit</a>
        </div>
```

visit : http://jsbin.com/iquxaq/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Jquery [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:**

> With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and **the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class**. With :eq(n) only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

**Solution**

Regardless to my tests,

- `$('div.myframe:nth-child(1)')` tries to look if div.myframe has a first child and if this element has **class="myframe"**. In that case it is `<span class="outfit-no">outfit no.<span>01</span></span>` so nothing is grabbed.
- After that for `$('div.myframe:nth-child(2)')` tries to grab the second child but it's still not a **.myframe**, it is `<a class="buy-outfit" href="#">Buy outfit</a>` so nothing is stored.
- Now `$('div.myframe:nth-child(3)')` tries to grab the third child and it's a **.myframe** since it's `<div class="myframe">` so it stores it.

**Alternative**

In your case [jquery eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector is more appropriate, it works great:

```
// select the first child    
$('div.myframe').eq(0);
// instead of
// $('div.myframe:nth-child(1)')
```

> With :eq(n) **only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted**,
>   not limited to children of any other element